# Как прочитать данную php переменную?

Tags: php, php7

Как прочитать данную php переменную?

```
$ignore = (in_array($dynamic_url,$ignore_pages))?true:false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Это так называемый тернарный оператор.

Синтаксис:

```
логическое_условие ? выражение_1 : выражение_2
```

Если логическое_условие истинно(возвращает true), то берётся (или вычисляется) первое выражение слева от двоеточия, если возвращается false, то берётся второе выражение справа от двоеточия.

Я так понимаю, что есть переменная $ignore и в зависимости от того, что возвращает функция

```
in_array($dynamic_url,$ignore_pages);
```

Ей присваивается значение true или false. А что конкретно туда передается и где это все дело потом применяется зависит от остального кода.

Answer (score 1):

Про тернарный оператор уже ответили, а я дополню, что

```
$ignore = (in_array($dynamic_url,$ignore_pages))?true:false;
```

не имеет никакого смысле т.к. `in_array` возвращает `bool` и этого:

```
$ignore = in_array($dynamic_url,$ignore_pages);
```

будет достаточно.